# How to call request in Postman

Tags: post, oauth, postman

I have request to rest api. Request from help page looks like:

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://allegro.pl/auth/oauth/device' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic base64(client_id:client_secret)' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'client_id={client_id}'
```

How to call above request from Postman? I've choosed POST type. In url I've pasted https://allegro.pl/auth/oauth/device.
But now I have problem. Which tab I should choose? On Authorization tab in Postman I have autorization type. And there is Basic Auth but I have to type username and password and I don't have both of them because I have only client id and secret id. On the Headers tab I can add two parameters: Authorization and Content-Type. But it doesn't work. I don't know if I should additionally put clientid:secretid into base64 and then past to the Value input?
Where I should past parameter -d clientid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, you can just import your `cUrl` to `Postman` as follow:

- Click on "import" tab on the upper left side.
- Select the Raw Text option and paste your cURL command.
- Hit import and you will have the command in your Postman builder!

Answering your questions:

> Which tab I should choose? On Authorization tab in Postman I have
> authorization type

You have two options:

- You chose `Authorization` tab, chose type as `Basic Auth`, and yes put `client_id` as Username and `client_secret` as Password, cause it concatenate them with a colon (:) in-between and base64-encode this string, check [Basic Auth RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617) for more details, and this will automatically set `Authorization` key in your headers.
- Or chose `Headers` tab, and paste directly the string if you have it ready encoded as `Basic base64({{client_id}}:{{client_secret}})`.

> Where I should past parameter -d clientid ?

That's your request body in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as keys and values, so you set key as `client_id` and value as `{{client_id}}`.